# Symfony3 - global flashbag message

Tags: php, symfony

I'm looking for a smart way to add a flashbag message for all logged in users. Any ideas?

Can I modify function `app.session.flashbag.all()`? For sure I can do my own method, but how to get active authenticated sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

You cannot have access for sessions other than the current one. That would be unsafe and also could lead to users blocking each other (session lock).

You should to that via some kind of storage like Redis etc.